# Convert Image DataType To String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a Column having `Image` datatype in MS-SQL SERVER 2012. I want to get it as string in SQL Query..

I have Tried This:

```
SELECT 
'empphoto : '+ ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), empphoto)),'') 
from emppersonal where --some condition

--empphoto Columns is of Image datatype
```

output looks corrupted (Just 4 characters).

OutPut looks like:

```
empphoto : ÿØÿà
```

[image]

How can be an `Image` datatype be converted to string in MS-SQL Server?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Before Updating Any row in table, I have to save that row data along with column name in some another table as a single string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can extract the image value as BASE64 by running it through `for xml path()`.

Try:

```sql
select 'empphoto : '+(select empphoto as '*' for xml path(''))
```

Result will look something like this.

```
empphoto : /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/wAARCADw
```

To go the other way you have to remove the first 11 characters (`empphoto :`), cast to XML and extract the value as `varbinary(max)`..

```sql
select cast(stuff(YourTextColumn, 1, 11, '') as xml).value('.', 'varbinary(max)')
```

Comment: ok,..If I have to insert it back to the same column empphoto `Image` datatype then how to cast it back

Comment: It looks working for `varbinry(max)` conversion. and not for `Image` datatype conversion

Comment: If I have to insert it back to the same column `empphoto` which is of `Image` datatype not `varbinary(max)`.Then shouldn't I need to cast to `Image` datatype instead of `varbinary(max)` as done above

Comment: @user3879765 There is an implicit conversion from `varbinary(max)` to `image`. Have you tried it? You should not change the code that extract the data. Keep `varbinary(max)` in there and an insert to an image field should work just fine. If not you have to show the code you use with table structures and the error message you get.

Comment: @user3879765 To remove the implicit conversion you can do an explicit conversion instead. `cast(cast(stuff(YourTextColumn, 1, 11, '') as xml).value('.', 'varbinary(max)') as image)`